# How to convert octal (unicode code point) to NSString in iOS

Tags: ios, string, nsstring, nslog, octal

I have a problem about converting.

```py
print "\357\274\221\357\274\221" # １１ , no problem!
```

In python, it works!

```c
NSLog(@"outCommand:%@", @"\357\274\221\357\274\221");// １ , loses another letter!
NSLog(@"outCommand:%@", [@"\357\274\221\357\274\221" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);// <efbc91ef bc91>
```

How can I convert it correctly in Objective-C or Swift on iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
char buf[]="\357\274\221\357\274\221";
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:buf];
NSLog(@"%@", str);
```

Comment: BTW, `NSLog(@"outCommand:%@", @"\357\274\221\357\274\221");` also works on my environment. Maybe it just has been wrapped in your output console?

Comment: Oh, thanks! Maybe Xcode or iOS have a bug about string, when it is attached a application process. It deletes a byte from string tail. (´•ω•｀)